# Flatten nested JSON into a keyed array of values using Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

From my server rest API, I request a javascript object that has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "msgID": 3,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Employee"
    }
  },
  {
    "msgID": 3,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Safety"
    }
  },
  {
    "msgID": 3,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Performance"
    }
  },
  {
    "msgID": 7,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Role Based Training"
    }
  },
  {
    "msgID": 7,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Account Service Information"
    }
  },
  {
    "msgID": 6,
    "admTag": {
      "tagName": "Consumer Product Safety Improvement"
    }
  }
]
```

To use this object on the client, I need to transform the structure to group by the `msgID` property and assign to it an array containing the values of the associated `tagName`. Like so:

```
[{
    "3": ["Employee","Safety","Performance"],
    "7": ["Role Based Training","Account Service Information"],
    "6": ["Consumer Product Safety Improvement"]
}]
```

I can accomplish this using a nested for loop but I know it can be done more efficiently and with less code using underscore.  Using groupBy I am able to get a grouping of the msgID's which gives me the keys I need:

```
_.groupBy(tags.tags, function(model){ 
  return model.msgID;
});
```

...but I'm unsure how to 'pluck' the tagNames from the resulting object and assign them to the proper msgID.

Greatly appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [*.groupBy*](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy), [.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) and [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) you could do something like this:

```
var output = _(input)
  .groupBy('msgID')                         // Group by msgId
  .mapValues(function(group) {              // Transform value of each group
    return _.map(group, 'admTag.tagName');  // Return array of tagNames
  })
  .value();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syfxcfqf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascript. Just four lines of code.

```js
var array = [{ "msgID": 3, "admTag": { "tagName": "Employee" } }, { "msgID": 3, "admTag": { "tagName": "Safety" } }, { "msgID": 3, "admTag": { "tagName": "Performance" } }, { "msgID": 7, "admTag": { "tagName": "Role Based Training" } }, { "msgID": 7, "admTag": { "tagName": "Account Service Information" } }, { "msgID": 6, "admTag": { "tagName": "Consumer Product Safety Improvement" } }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    result[a.msgID] = result[a.msgID] || [];
    result[a.msgID].push(a.admTag.tagName);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [_.reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) from underscore

```js
var result = _.reduce(tags.tags, function(l, r) {
    if (typeof l[r.msgID] === "undefined") {
        l[r.msgID] = [];
    }
    l[r.msgID].push(r.admTag.tagName);
    return l;
}, {});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjy2qw3n/)

The same can be achieved with the native [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with nearly the same code

```js
var result = tags.tags.reduce(function(l, r) {
    if (typeof l[r.msgID] === "undefined") {
        l[r.msgID] = [];
    }
    l[r.msgID].push(r.admTag.tagName);
    return l;
}, {});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqj9kf4y/)